# pymysql issue 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, mysql

Hi i'm trying to use pymysql. Here is the simpliest code

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd=None,
                       db='newbase')
```

and i'm getting error:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'.
i'm using easyphp5.3.6.0
What should i do ?

Comment: Please post more of your code and the callstack from python. None password should be no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a problem with `passwd=None` parameter. Try to specify password as some string or do not pass this parameter.